# Python loop syntax error?

Tags: python, loops, syntax, for-loop

Why will this not compile... I am stumped...

```
for files in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    f=open(files)
    for lines in f:
        print lines
```

I get:

```
File "teleparse.py", line 21
for lines in f:
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces in the indentation space?

Comment: your 2nd for-loop and the print have tabs in front of them - at least in what you have posted, replace with spaces. As the PEP8 states [never  mix tabs and spaces](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces). PEP8 recommends spaces over tabs.

Comment: No, i've made sure that the indentations contain only tabs.

Comment: Well - according to PEP8, it should only really be spaces :) But nevermind, that's what's happening...

Comment: MAde sure means you do not know it!

Comment: Ok, yea it was something dumb on my part, need some sleep.

Comment: Editing your question showed a mix of tabs and spaces. I modified the code to display in the OP just like it looked "raw". There are obvious issues with the tabbing.

Comment: @Paul, wait, why did you do that? Why not leave the tabs as they were to keep the question consistent with Levon's comment and DSM's answer?

Comment: I wouldn't delete this question - I'm just voting to close - be unfair to lose the info. we have here (even if it is somewhat duplicated)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I made the edit before there were any answers posted. And yes, it is inconsistent now. I will try and revert the changes.

Answer (score 6):

"No, i've made sure that the indentations contain only tabs."

You're wrong:

```
>>> s = """
... 
...     for files in glob.glob("*.txt"):
...         f=open(files)
...         for lines in f:
...                 print lines
... """
>>> 
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...     print repr(line)
... 
''
''
'    for files in glob.glob("*.txt"):'
'        f=open(files)'
'\t    for lines in f:'
'\t\t    print lines'
```

You can use `python -tt yourprogramname.py` to confirm that you're mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: I'll just throw in http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/tabnanny/ for good measure

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the potential mixing of tabs and spaces (see [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)), why is your second `for`-loop indented after the open file?

Should be like this (preferably using only spaces):

```
for files in glob.glob("*.txt"):
   f=open(files)
   for lines in f:
      print lines
```

not

```
for files in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    f=open(files)
         for lines in f:
            print lines
```

which *would* be an "unexpected indent" as the error message states.

Comment: @downvoters .. and the problem with this is?

Comment: Not my downvote, but from the OP's perspective the inner loop didn't look indented.  The original loop looked just fine (see the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13996762/revisions)), and due to a well-meaning but I think unfortunate edit it now looks different.

Comment: @Levon you are editing your question so many times, even after it was already neatly answered by DSM, that it is difficult to say why I downvoted it at some moment. Anyway I turn the vote back to you, as your answer now looks fine ;-)

Comment: @DSM: My bad. I reverted the code to its original formatting.

Comment: Ah .. so I got downvoted because the original question was edited? There was clearly a problem with mixing tabs and spaces (see my original comment above) and then I noticed the off indentation in addition and posted this answer. (I was having problems with editing my answer, browser as acting weirdly).

Comment: @Levon: hey to you too.  We must keep different SO hours these days. ;^)

Comment: @DSM no, I've been super busy with work .. but have a short break now .. though I've kept an eye on SO, but not had time to post.